# How to get "Data Type" value of Body of a Lotus Notes Item using .NET?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am trying to get Data Type (Body Format) of Mail,Calendar e.t.c. Body.

Getting Body content as:

```
String Body = (string)((object[])docInbox.GetItemValue("Body"))[0];
```

or

```
String Body = docInbox.GetFirstItem("Body").Text;
```

I tried it using:

```
String bodyFormat = ((object[])docInbox.GetItemValue("Body"))[0].GetType().ToString();
```

But in this case i am getting "System.String" value.But actually it is : "Rich Text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the Notes data type of the "Body" item, you can use the Type property of the NotesItem class. For example:

```
...
dim itemBody as notesItem, nType as integer
set itemBody = doc.getItem ("Body")
nType = itemBody.Type
...
```

RichText is 1, Text is 1280, Numeric is 768, etc. Domino Designer Help has the full list of values.

EDIT: You can find the full list of Type values [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/6b75d4e88ca060e88525704a0040d111?OpenDocument):

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
NotesRichTextItem rtItem = docInbox.GetFirstItem("Body")

String body = rtItem.GetFormattedText(False, 0)

or

String body = rtItem.GetUnformattedText()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're now getting the value through GetItemValue("Body"). Isn't there a method like

```
GetItem("Body")
```

which contains this information?

Comment: It's Lotus Notes, they have no sensible set of properties and methods like .NET has in most cases :)

Comment: Ah well, at least I was in the right direction :-) it was more to show that only getting the value wasn't getting hem anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for You item in Items collection and then You can do

```
docInbox.Items[foundBodyItemIndex].Type
```

RichText has "1"