# LotusScript: getItemValue("Body") splits paragraphs into several lines

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

getItemValue("Body") does not retrieve the paragraph of the email correctly, it splits it into several lines.

the body of my email is the following:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut nec consectetur odio. Donec vulputate ultrices facilisis. Curabitur finibus, eros ut malesuada efficitur, lacus felis suscipit neque, at ultricies odio felis imperdiet metus. Sed non tellus ut metus elementum efficitur auctor ut urna. Aliquam placerat justo eu elementum elementum. Integer sodales iaculis ligula et sollicitudin. Vivamus vel quam ornare, tristique lorem at, interdum erat. Nam pharetra dui vel orci semper posuere. Suspendisse bibendum, eros non maximus tristique, dui dolor imperdiet erat, ut feugiat dolor urna eu urna. Maecenas sed quam dolor. Phasellus ultricies, mi eu efficitur mattis, massa massa pretium arcu, non placerat massa nunc eu nisi. Nullam sit amet tempus nisl.

But I get that in the end:

[image: Result of getItemValue("Body")]

My code is as follows:

```
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim varValues As Variant
    Dim valueBody As String
    
    If Not ws.Currentdocument Is Nothing Then
        Set doc = ws.Currentdocument.Document
    Elseif Not session.DocumentContext Is Nothing Then
        Set doc = session.DocumentContext
    End If

    varValues = doc.GetItemValue( "Body" )
    MessageBox varValues(0)
```

How can I retrieve a paragraph in one piece?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1426778/785061

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten Thank you for your help. Maybe that can help me, but I don't know how. How do you think this can help me?

Comment: You could try to use the rtItem.GetformattedText (or rtItem.GetUnformattedText) method to retrieve the content of the rich text field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the field as a `NotesRichTextItem` field and then use the `GetformattedText` or `GetUnformattedText` method to retrieve the content of the rich text field.

Answer (score 0):

With your help, I found a solution. Just need to use **GetUnformattedText()** from *NotesRichTextItem*, as in the example below:

```
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim varValues As Variant
    Dim valueBody As String
    Dim rtItem  As NotesRichTextItem
    
    If Not ws.Currentdocument Is Nothing Then
        Set doc = ws.Currentdocument.Document
    Elseif Not session.DocumentContext Is Nothing Then
        Set doc = session.DocumentContext
    End If

    Set rtItem = doc.GetFirstItem("Body")
    varValues = rtItem.GetUnformattedText()
    MessageBox varValues
```

Thank you for your help